# ios CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to skew an object cards it's an UIView I'm doing :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:DEPLACEMENT_ANIMATION_DUREE_SECONDES_DROITE];
scene.carte17.layer.position = positionInit;
if (scene.carte17.angleCarte == 15.f) {
    scene.carte17.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(scene.carte17.transform, degreesToRadians(30));
    scene.carte17.angleCarte = 45.f;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And it's working ! My card incline to 30° and it's good. I'm playing with setAnimationDuration to control the speed.

I would like to use  CoreAnimation and kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut to have a better animation but I'm not ok to do the same think with core animation I'm trying this :

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:.5f];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
scene.carte17.layer.position = positionInit;
if (scene.carte17.angleCarte == 15.f) {
    CABasicAnimation *animation;
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(scene.carte17.transform, degreesToRadians(30))];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.delegate = self;
    [scene.carte17.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    scene.carte17.angleCarte = 45.f;
}
[CATransaction commit];
```

But it's not working ... Could you help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call this:

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

But that is an overkill since `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` is the default value.

Comment: Thank you PeyloW very helpfull ! I'm new and it's hard for me to make the exact differnece between CoreAnimation and the animation in UIKit ... but I'm working on !

Comment: @MaRiriAndMe can you  please take a look at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854367/rotating-image-multiple-times-and-stopping-at-desired-degree